# Легальность функции-обертки функции-члена

Tags: c++, c++17

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() {};
    ~Foo() {};
    void foo() { std::cout << "Hello from Foo:foo" << std::endl; }
    void bar(const int& i) { std::cout << "Hello from Foo:bar. i = " << i << std::endl; }
    int foobar(const int& i){ return i; }
};

template <typename function_t, typename object_t, typename... args_t>
decltype(auto) safe_call(function_t _function, object_t* _object, args_t&&... _args)
{
    if (_object != nullptr)
        return (_object->*_function)(std::forward<args_t>(_args)...);

//  throw std::exception("object is null"); // Commented
}

int main()
{
    Foo* pobj2 = new Foo();
    Foo* pobj3 = nullptr;

    try
    {
        safe_call(&Foo::foo, pobj2);
        safe_call(&Foo::bar, pobj2,  2);
        std::cout << safe_call(&Foo::foobar, pobj2, 42) << std::endl;

        safe_call(&Foo::foo, pobj3);     // Раз
        safe_call(&Foo::bar, pobj3,  3); // Два
        std::cout << safe_call(&Foo::foobar, pobj3, 42) << std::endl; // Три
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

Итак имеем функцию-обертку `safe_call`, которая проверяет валидность указателя и бросает исключение, если он нуловый.

Коментим бросок исключения. Содержит ли теперь данный код ub с точки зрения стандарта в случаях Раз, Два, Три?

И как можно перевести данную функцию на работу без исключений, чтобы она возвращала неинициализированное значение по типу возврата функции-члена?
Т.е. если мы передаем функцию `int foo()` чтобы возврат был `return int{};` аналогично `CustomClass bar()` -> `return CustomClass{};`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, без `throw` данный код содержит UB, именно в вызове

```
safe_call(&Foo::foobar, pobj3, 42)
```

В C++ для UB уже достаточно просто "забыть" вернуть значение из non-void функции, независимо от того, использует ли вызывающий код это значение.

Сделать возврат значения, инициализированного по умолчанию, можно "выцарапав" из типа функции тип его возвращаемого значения. Для именно вашего набора шаблонных аргументов

```
template <typename function_t, typename object_t, typename... args_t>
decltype(auto) safe_call(function_t _function, object_t* _object, args_t&&... _args)
{
    if (_object != nullptr)
        return (_object->*_function)(std::forward<args_t>(_args)...);

    using R = typename std::result_of<function_t(object_t *, args_t...)>::type;
    return R();
}
```

Обратите внимание - здесь придется использовать именно `R()`, а не `R{}`, ибо последнее не допускает типа `void`.

P.S. `std::result_of` является deprecated. Вместо него следует использовать `std::invoke_result`

Comment: Спасибо, я чуть-чуть не дошел до R() все пытался со списком инициализации сделать. Получается для void типа будет идти что-то близкое к return void() ?

Comment: @goldstar_labs: Да, будет именно обычный `return void();`